# Select one row from one table and multiple rows from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a little ago, but I find my question so bad, that it actually didn't help me do what I wanted, so I deleted it and tried again.

I have a table in my database called 'game' with the columns: k1, k1r, k2, k2r, k3, k3r, grp and week. The week-column is automatically inserted with the week of the year and the others are user-inputs from a betting game I made.

Then I have a table called 'matches' with the columns: match1, match2, match3, grp, week. Again, same procedure with the week-column. The other 4 I fill out with the matches we should bet on. The 'grp' column in both is filled by me with 'BS' and 'VF'.

I then have a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM game 
WHERE week = '.$week.' AND grp = 'bs';
```

`$week` is already set as `$week = Date('W');`

It outputs a table, where I write the matches in 3 columns and then echoes the users bets in the rows under the matches. But instead of me changing the php-script every time there are new matches, I would like it to take them from the table 'matches'. In that way, I also keep the old matches in the database.

So, now to my question :)

What I would like to do is something like:

```
'SELECT * FROM game WHERE week = '.$week.' AND grp = 'bs' 
       JOIN * FROM matches WHERE week = '.$week.' AND grp = 'bs';
```

but as you probably now, that won't work :/

In my other question I forgot to mention the 'grp' column and couldn't figure out how to insert it.

To echo it I used:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$no = 1;

$amount = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
echo '<tr>
<td><strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong></td>

<td>'.$row['k1']."<br />".$row['k1r'].'</td>

<td>'.$row['k2']."<br />".$row['k2r'].'</td>

<td>'.$row['k3']."<br />".$row['k3r'].'</td> }
```

but I would like an outcome like this:

```
|       |Match1    |Match2    |Match3    |
|User1  |2-0       |2-1       |2-2       |
|User2  |1-1       |2-2       |1-2       |
```

And so on ... where the 'Matches' are selected from the 'matches'-table and the bets are selected from the 'game'-table. So I just need the one row from 'Matches' as the headline and then loop through the rows in 'Game'.

The creates are:

```
CREATE TABLE `game` 
(
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `k1` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `k1r` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `k2` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `k2r` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `k3` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `k3r` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `week` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `grp` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`uid`,`week`,`grp`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE `udvalgte_kampe` 
(
    `hold1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `hold2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `hold3` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `hold4` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `hold5` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `hold6` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `week` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `grp` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci
```

But what should I do then?

Comment: Could you provide the CREATE statements and one or two rows per table to clarify your question?

Comment: Sure. Added the Create statements. Not sure how to add a row? Should I just write it down? Or can I do something like with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to track. You have a bunch of users and you wanna know how they scored in all matches combined per week?

Comment: @Sebastian I see. It's hard to descripe :) Ehm, I have a form, that the users fill out and submit with 3 matches where they bet who's winning and the score of the match. That's inserted into the 'game' table. So now i have a table on my frontend showing the 3 matches and selecting the data from the 'game'-table. But instead of me changing the matches in the code every week, I would like it to autmatically select the mathes from the table 'matches' at the right week of the year. Makes anymore sense? :/

Comment: Thanks for adding the creates, however, you show the table **udvalgte_kampe** instead of **matches**

Comment: Yeah, my bad. The table **udvalgte_kampe** is the right table - I just changed the name to english - therefore **matches** :)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware for sql injection using $var and  you can avoid string concatenation using proper quotes.

your second query   the sintax for join is 
is wrong  youn should use this sintax

```
"SELECT * FROM game 
JOIN matches on game.week  = matches.week 
where WHERE game.week = '$week' AND game.grp = 'bs'";
```

and not

```
'SELECT * FROM game WHERE week = '.$week.' AND grp = 'bs' 
   JOIN * FROM matches WHERE week = '.$week.' AND grp = 'bs';
```

Comment: That actually worked, but when I echo it, the row from 'Matches' shows in between every row from 'game'-table. I only want the row from 'Matches' to be shown once as the table-header. :/

Comment: Slight amendment to your code. Daniel's original code suggests the tables should be joined on grp as well as week : "SELECT * FROM game 
JOIN matches on game.week  = matches.week AND game.grp = matches.grp
WHERE game.week = '$week' AND game.grp = 'bs'";

Comment: @Daniel: Showing the matches once is done in the PHP code. The SQL results will have the data from each column in every row.

Comment: @SloanThrasher So it can't be done? It's because I should use the same matches in 6 different PHP-sites, so I hoped it could be done like this, so I only have to change it at one place instead of 6 :)

Comment: Of course it can be done. Like I said, you format the SQL results in your PHP code. Output the match only once, and the other data for each row.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Maybe it's possible to make some kind of global $, so if I call the variables like `$match1` in every page, I just have to change them at one place?

Comment: @SloanThrasher oh, so it can be done :D But as far as I know, I should use `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);` and then it uses just that one row, but then it also just use one row from the 'game'-table. I tried using `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))` but then it shows the row each time.

Comment: Your code decides what to output inside the while loop. If there is a value you only want to show once, you can add a loop counter and a if statement to only output it once.

Comment: In the SQL results, there aren't two tables. The data may come from two tables, but when going through the results, it appear the same as if it was one table.

Comment: If you have phpAdmin available, you might try you query there to get a feel for how the query works.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Oh, okay. Guess it's out of my expertise :D Thought I could make it easier for myself ;) I also tried to write the variables and then include that one file, but I'm using Joomla and don't know how to include an article. Guess I'll keep trying :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SQL from the previous answer, I think this is roughly what you would need in your PHP :

```
$headerPrinted = $false;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    if (!headerPrinted) {
        echo '<th>
            <td></td>
            <td>'.$row['hold1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['hold2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['hold3'].'</td>
        </th>';
        $headerPrinted = $true;
    }

    $no = 1;

    $amount = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
    echo '<tr>
    <td><strong>'.$row['name'].'</strong></td>

    <td>'.$row['k1']."<br />".$row['k1r'].'</td>

    <td>'.$row['k2']."<br />".$row['k2r'].'</td>

    <td>'.$row['k3']."<br />".$row['k3r'].'</td>';

}
```

I'm making the assumption that hol1, hold2 and hold3 are the columns you want to use for your header.

I'm not saying this is the best way to achieve what you want, but it's probably good enough for your current level of experience.

Comment: P.S. It's a while since I've done any PHP, and I've done a lot of C# and other languages since, then so I've probably made a load of syntax errors :)

Comment: Well, I can't get that to work. Can't get it to echo anything, but I think it's my mistake :D Sorry, so bad at this :)